# Arden's rule expressed as matrix algebra

Tags: regular-languages, combinatorics, matrices

> The following theorem is (in the context of languages) known as
>   Arden's Lemma: Given a linear system $X = B+AX$ and the matrix A is
>   quasiregular, then we have a solution which is unique and which
>   preserves rationality. In the next lemma we show the converse: For
>   every rational series we can find a linear system such that the first
>   component of its solution vector is exactly the given series. With
>   these two results we have already done most of the work for proving
>   the Theorem of Schutzenberger, which teaches us that the families of
>   rational and recognizable series coincide.
>
> ## Theorem 2.2.1
>
> Let $B \in \mathbb{K}\langle\langle\Sigma^*\rangle\rangle^{n,1}$ and $A \in \mathbb{K}\langle\langle\Sigma^*\rangle\rangle^{n,n}$ a quasiregular matrix. The linear
>   system
>
> $$
> X = B + AX
> $$
>
> has the unique solution $X = A^∗B$. Moreover, if $A$
>   and $B$ are $\mathbb{K}-rational$ then the solution $X$ is $\mathbb{K}-rational$.
>
> ### Proof:
>
> First we show that $X = A^∗B$ is a solution:
>
> $$
> B + AX = B + AA^∗ B = (I + AA^∗)B = A^∗B = X.
> $$

My question is as follows: what does asterisk mean in this context (when it is used with matrices)? I know what Arden's Lemma is, but I don't understand the proof given here.

To credit the author of this paper: Regular Languages And Their Generating Functions: The Inverse Problem by Christoph Koutschan.

Comment: This is not the classical Arden's lemma. If you can't understand the notation in the proof, you probably can't understand the result itself.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).

Comment: @D.W. I will do it tomorrow, this is a lot of work and it is early morning here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for encouragement :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation is probably defined in the paper or in some standard reference, but one can guess that
$$
A^* = (I - A)^{-1}.
$$
This definition satisfies the identity $A^* = I+AA^*$, since
$$
I+AA^* = I-((I-A)-I)A^* = I-(I-A)A^*+A^* = I-I+A^* = A^*.
$$
Presumably a quasiregular matrix $A$ is one for which $I-A$ is invertible, perhaps with some additional assumptions.

Comment: Your answer is optimal if $K$ is a ring, but I suspect that here $K$ might be a semiring, to cover the case of the Boolean semiring, which gives back the case of languages. A series is *quasi-regular* if the coefficient of the empty word is $0$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin yes, thank you for this comment. $K$ is indeed a semiring in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This is [the Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).  The Kleene star is [defined for any monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star#Generalization).  It is sometimes defined as

$$A^* = 1 + A + A^2 + A^3 + \cdots$$

(given a suitable notion of convergence, and assuming the sum converges).  Here $1$ is the identity -- in this case, the identity matrix.  In monoids that have division, we can refer to our intuition that $1 + A + A^2 + A^3 + \cdots = 1/(1-A)$, and equivalently define

$$A^* = (1-A)^{-1},$$

when the inverse exists.  In your case, the inverse is simply the matrix inverse, and as before, $1$ is the identity matrix.

---

Alternatively, the Kleene star of $A$ can be defined as the element $A^*$ satisfying

$$A^* = 1 + A A^* = 1 + A^* A.$$

In other words, if there is an element $Z$ such that

$$Z = 1 + A Z = 1 + ZA,$$

then we say that $Z$ is the Kleene star of $A$, written $A^* = Z$.  Again, $1$ represents the identity in the underlying monoid/semiring -- in this case, the identity matrix.

---

See also the notion of a [star semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Star_semirings).  For instance, matrices form a star semiring.